# assigning a combobox selection to a binding list

Tags: c#

I have a combo box done on my Windows GUI with the code below:

```
 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
        if (comboBox.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
           //players binding list == 2 or in other words, players binding list = comboBox 

        }
```

When the number in the combo box gets changed, I want to change the number of players on the board to the number that has been selected and set them back at the start square, problem is I cannot figure out how to update the number of players with the number chosen in the combo box.

The other code I have which determines the number of players is here:

```
namespace SharedGameClasses {
/// <summary>
/// Plays a game called Hare and the Tortoise
/// </summary>
public class HareAndTortoiseGame {


    private Board board;
    public Board Board {
        get {
            return board;
        }
    }

    private Die die1, die2;

    // A BindingList is like an array that can grow and shrink. 
    // 
    // Using a BindingList will make it easier to implement the GUI with a DataGridView
    private BindingList<Player> players = new BindingList<Player>();
    public BindingList<Player> Players {
        get {
            return players;
        }
    }



    // Minimum and maximum players.
    private const int MIN_PLAYERS = 2;
    public const int MAX_PLAYERS = 6;

    private int numberOfPlayers = 2;  // The value 2 is purely to avoid compiler errors.

    public int NumberOfPlayers {
        get {
            return numberOfPlayers;
        }
        set {
            numberOfPlayers = value;
        }
    }
```

I have tried so many ways of assigning the comb box selection to max players and Player, players etc.. but have not found a way to make it work yet. Does anyone have any ideas? thank you in advance.

Comment: You may want to tag this message with "winforms" or "wpf" to attract more expertise. It's not clear which you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` you can try to parse the combobox `SelectedItem` property.

Sample:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;

    HareAndTortoiseGame.NumberOfPlayers = (int)(comboBox.SelectedItem);        
}
```

Comment: thank you but i now need to create an object reference for HareAndTortoiseGame.NumberOfPlayers = (int)(comboBox.SelectedItem);  is this just a case of creating a new variable with HareAndTortoiseGame.NumberOfPlayers = (int)(comboBox.SelectedItem);  in it?

Comment: If your event subscription and your property are inside the same class `HareAndTortoiseGame`, you can just use `this.NumberOfPlayers = (int)(comboBox.SelectedItem);`. Otherwise, inside the class that owns your event, create an instance of `HareAndTortoiseGame`: `HareAndTortoiseGame game = new HareAndTortoiseGame();`

Comment: thanks i sorted it out with your help. I was not parsing correctly. best regards.

Comment: Great, I'm happy to have been of help.